# Match two jsonb documents by order of elements in array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have table of data jsonb documents in postgres and second table containing templates for data.

I need to match data jsonb row with template jsonb row just by order of elements in array in effective way.

template jsonb document:

```
{
   "template":1,
   "rows":[
      "first row",
      "second row",
      "third row"
   ]
}
```

data jsonb document:

```
{
   "template":1,
   "data":[
      125,
      578,
      445
   ]
}
```

desired output:

| Desc | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| first row | 125 |
| second row | 578 |
| third row | 445 |

template table:

```
| id        | jsonb                                                  |
| --------  | ------------------------------------------------------ |
| 1         | {"template":1,"rows":["first row","second row","third row"]}           |
| 2         | {"template":2,"rows":["first row","second row","third row"]}           |
| 3         | {"template":3,"rows":["first row","second row","third row"]}           |
```

data table:

```
| id        | jsonb                                         |
| --------  | -------------------------------------------   |
| 1         | {"template":1,"data":[125,578,445]}           |
| 2         | {"template":1,"data":[125,578,445]}           |
| 3         | {"template":2,"data":[125,578,445]}           |
```

I have millions of data jsonb documents and hundreds of templates.

I would do it just by converting both to tables, then use `row_number` windowed function but it does not seem very effective way to me.

Is there better way of doing this?

Comment: How are the two tables related? Is there any foreign key between them? Or any other column that can be used to join the two tables? Or do you only have a single row in each table with one gigantic JSON value?

Comment: Each data json doc has own id (irrelevant I guess) and each template has its id column as well. I could add new column to data table by extracting template id for each data document if that would help - so there would be direct link between those two.

Comment: I have added table examples.

Comment: So the two tables can be joined via the `id` colum? Or only via the value of the `template` key?

Comment: Only via template key.

Comment: What should happen if `data` has more or less items in `rows` than the `template` has? Are `null` values ok in such cases, or exit with error message?

Comment: That should not happen (in this case) but in such a case rather raise error as it might assign wrong lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to normalize this mess "on-the-fly" to get the output you want.

You need to unnest each array using `jsonb_array_elements()` using the `with ordinality` option to get the array index. You can join the two tables by extracting the value of the `template` key:

Assuming you want to return this for a specific row from the data table:

```
select td.val, dt.val
from data 
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(data.jsonb_column -> 'data') with ordinality as dt(val, idx)
  left join template tpl 
         on tpl.jsonb_column ->> 'template' = data.jsonb_column ->> 'template'
  left join jsonb_array_elements_text(tpl.jsonb_column -> 'rows') with ordinality as td(val, idx) 
         on td.idx = dt.idx
where data.id = 1;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cfd2ec3afac4be520eb7d59ac93b7d81)